# Grunt Js File Path Revision Inside Script Files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am trying to write a grunt task which changes the reference file path inside the script files so that works in both development and production environment.

Unfortunately this is not updating the referential path of the JSON file I am referring to.

**Development Environment**

```
angular.module('appModernizationApp')
    .controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'HRS', 
                                '$location', '$routeParams',
                                'breadcrumbs', 'UtilitiesService', 
function($scope, $http, HRS, $location, $routeParams, breadcrumbs, UtilitiesService) {

        if (breadcrumbs.breadcrumbs.length >= 3) {
            breadcrumbs.breadcrumbs.splice(1, 1);
        }

        $http.get('../../data/dropdown-data.json').success(function(data) {
            console.log("Data:" + JSON.stringify(data.dropdownData));
        });
```

In development environment I have to use **../../data/dropdown-data.json** because the folder structure is like below. This **JSON** file is referred from 2 levels beneath - **scripts/controllers/details.js** in development environment

[image: Image showing from where data/dropdown-data.json is accessed from in development environment]

Where as **Production Environment** it works if I have **../data/dropdown-data.json** because of the below folder structure after compression and concatination. The **JSON** file is referred from 1 level below **scripts/scripts.js**

[image: Image showing from where data/dropdown-data.json is accessed from in production environment]

My production code still refers to the file @ location:

```
$http.get('../../data/dropdown-data.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log("Data:" + JSON.stringify(data.dropdownData));
});
```

which I want to automatically change it to **../data/dropdown-data.json**

My Grunt Task:

```
filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g,
              'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },
```

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/eruizdechavez/grunt-string-replace) plugin should be helpful